# Replacing remote lock fuse on 2001 Jetta/Bora VW

Tags: locks, fuse

So! This starts with a fun story. I had a flat battery and my friend who isn't really a techie/mechie sort of person came to lend me a hand, I had leads and he had a car, his car has a red coloured lead on the NEGATIVE terminal, so he made the mistake of reversing the polarity, blowing the stereo fuse and who knows what else in my car.

I've removed the stereo and am going to replace that fuse. I've checked the fuses in the side panel reasonably well and they are all fine, the only thing not working is the remote fob which isn't the end of the world, however I also have one of the not so good lights on the dash lit up http://www.vwforum.com/forums/f15/2002-jetta-dash-lights-42589/ - the one with the warning and arrow going round it. I'd prefer not to take it to a mechanics for a fuse replacement, if that is actually what is needed.

So any advice on tracking down the fuse/module for this would be amazing or if you know that I've destroyed something that would be great to know.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This a warning for the engines immobiliser. *Re-programme the keys: With a key switch the ignition on, insert key to be programmed into the drivers door and manually lock the vehicle, press the lock button once, wait a couple of seconds and press the lock button once again. The vehicles horn should beep to let you know the key has been programmed. Repeat for any other keys, up to four.* If your light remains on after a successful reprogramming of the keys, then your ECU will need to be re-set using a VW compatable diagnostic scanner.

Comment: Hi Allan - did you go to the link and see the picture? It's not the immo, it's [the ASR and ABS lights](https://c1.staticflickr.com/3/2344/1855860792_f026f1b329.jpg). These ALWAYS come on for me together as a pair; I strongly suspect that the computer's detecting a fault in the ABS module or related system.